# How do I divide the driver value?

Tags: drivers

I have an Empty `x`-position driving the rotation of a Cube.

And I want to divide the value of the position of the Empty, so that the Cube rotates half the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a single driver to the cube (e.g. Z-rotation)
- Go to *Graph Editor* and switch to *Drivers* mode
- Set *Ob/Bone* of the variable `var` to reference the Empty
- Enter the *Expr*ession `var/2` (or `var*0.5`)

[image: Simple Driver Setup using a variable]

`var` is equal to the *X Location* of the Empty, dividing it by 2 halves the "influence" of the location to the rotation of the Cube.